# ListView inside Flingable Tabhost?

Tags: android, listview, android-tabhost, gesture

Google's homegrown YouTube app (2.3.4), when displayed in portait layout, has a flingable TabHost with a scrollable ListView inside it displaying related videos.

I would like the same functionality, a ListView within a "flingable" TabHost, with the same great fluid response/behaviour . I'm a massive noob and have honestly no clue how to achieve even a simple tabhost let alone place a vertically scrolling listview inside it and fling the tabs over with horizontal gestures.

I've looked around and the IOScheduler app source code that was suggested as a resource in another answer is 404'd. Any help?

Thanks very much, have a great day.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [Android support library](http://developer.android.com/sdk/compatibility-library.html) provides the [ViewPager](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/view/ViewPager.html) class which does just this.

There are samples included in the support lib download (available from SDK manager).

Answer (score 0):

You should give [this](https://github.com/pakerfeldt/android-viewflow) a try.

It's an open-source project so you can examine the source code and make changes.

I hope it helps...